# Drawing line and points in PySide2 with coordination

Tags: python, pyside2, qpainter

I want to draw some lines and points by PySide2 and I followed the documentations and provide code below, but it is not showing any thing after I call the function.

```
class Window2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Deformed Structure")

        self.DrawWindows = QtGui.QWindow()

        self.DrawButton23 = QPushButton('Draw', self)
        self.DrawButton23.setStyleSheet("Background-color: orange")
        self.DrawButton23.move(100, 200)
        self.DrawButton23.show()

        self.DrawButton23.clicked.connect(self.PaintEvent)

    def PaintEvent(self, painter):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter()
        painter.begin(self)
        pen = QPen(Qt.green)
        painter.setPen(pen)

        for i in range(0, 10):
            x0 = i * 30
            y0 = i * 30
            x1 = 100 + i * 50
            y1 = 100 + i * 50
            point1 = QPointF(x0, y0)
            point2 = QPointF(x1, y1)
            line1 = QLineF(point1, point2)
            painter.drawPoint(point1)
            painter.drawLine(line1)
            print("OK123") #Just to check the loop, it prints 10 time

        painter.end()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must understand that:

- Python and C++ are case sensitive so paintEvent is different from PaintEvent.
- You should not invoke paintEvent directly but using the update() or repaint() method.
- From what I understand is that you want the painting to be executed when you press the button but you cannot control the painting directly, the logic is to activate a certain part of the painting using some flag.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Window2(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Deformed Structure")

        self.flag = False

        self.draw_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Draw", self)
        self.draw_button.setStyleSheet("Background-color: orange")
        self.draw_button.move(100, 200)

        self.draw_button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

    def on_clicked(self):
        self.flag = True
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)

        if self.flag:
            pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.green)
            painter.setPen(pen)
            for i in range(0, 10):
                x0 = i * 30
                y0 = i * 30
                x1 = 100 + i * 50
                y1 = 100 + i * 50
                point1 = QtCore.QPointF(x0, y0)
                point2 = QtCore.QPointF(x1, y1)
                line1 = QtCore.QLineF(point1, point2)
                painter.drawPoint(point1)
                painter.drawLine(line1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
    w = Window2()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I updated my question now. Your code worked in a separate file. However it just draw one line, it seems that the 'for' loop is working one step at a time and what I see is the last loop drawing. I am not sure about this!

Comment: @MohoTa No, the loop works but your lines are collinear plus they intersect so visually it looks like you draw a single line.

Comment: Secondly, as I updated my question, you can see that I have a MainWindow and Window2. Still, when I import your code into mine, the second window opens correctly with the "draw_button" but as I push the button its not drawing at all.

Comment: @MohoTa Have you read my answer? It seems not. I recommend you reread it and analyze it.

Comment: I am sorry, You are right, I did not know that 'paintEvent' is actually a built-in-function.Thank you for your help